# Root access in Jelastic Cloud

Tags: php, ssh, apache2, root, jelastic

I am unable to run supervisord for PHP in one of the container, its asking for Apache Password and doesnt have root access

Trying : **sudo systemctl start supervisord.service**

Dev_Container was running on PHP 8.0 and before that I imported JPS script to get the root access and it worked. Now I switched my PHP version to 8.1 and after importing JPS script, it shows Sudoers syntax error but the same JPS script works well before.

I have also tried **sudo /etc/init.d/supervisord** start but this wont work

Any Help to get the sudo access?
[image]

Comment: This is a big problem `Sudoers syntax error`. Can you `sudo bash`?

Comment: Issue resolved, but took lot of time.

Comment: It is ok to answer your own question if you care to share your problem resolution with the interwebs.